# Why JAVA_HOME not recognized by tomcat7 in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I have installed tomcat7 on my Ubuntu machine. When I try to restart the server I get message to set JAVA_HOME but it is set in .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
```

Error:

```
omkars@<ubuntu_14.04>:~$ sudo service tomcat7 restart
[sudo] password for omkars: 
 * no JDK or JRE found - please set JAVA_HOME
omkars@<ubuntu_14.04>:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

What could be missing ?
Thanks.

Comment: First: You export the environment variables as "omkars" and start "tomcat7" as root using `sudo`; the environments won't be passed to that process. Second: I don't have Ubuntu at hand but: on RedHat/CentOS there are application server configs under `/etc/` specifying environments to use for startup. Try to grep `/etc` for "JAVA_HOME".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Now, its working!

Changes I have done are:

- changed `.bashrc` as explained in the question.
- changed `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` to **point to oracle Java8 which is missing here!**

  ```
  JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle**"
  ```

Then,

```
root@omkars-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~# sudo service tomcat7 restart 
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ]
```

Got a hint from this page:
https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/MIFOSX/Install+Tomcat+7+on+Ubuntu+11.10+for+Mifos+X

Thanks

Comment: You should accept this as the correct answer. The problem is because the Ubuntu init.d startup script (if installed via apt-get) for Tomcat does not check for a java 8 jdk.

Comment: Thanks @Omkar your answer is very helpful.

Comment: This answer appears very useful. I need to edit the file of concern inside a Vagrant provisioned virtual machine. The given line does not exist anymore.

Comment: This answer helped me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

It seems like the preferred way of handling this is to uncomment the JAVA_HOME entry in `/etc/default/tomcat7` and adjust the path accordingly.  If you're using the webupd8 repository with the oracle-java8-installer, it's `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.

Answer (score 3):

It'll need to be set for the user that runs the tomcat service, rather than for your user.

Set it in the system wide profile, somewhere in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/`, depending on how your machine is configured.

Answer (score 3):

The startup script at `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` sources the file `/etc/default/rcS` before searching for some well-known install locations.

Adding the line `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` to `/etc/default/rcS` corrects the `no JDK or JRE found` startup problem without directly modifying the `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` script.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an environmental variable in the `setenv.sh` script. According to the [*Running The Apache Tomcat 7.0*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) document:

> Apart from CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE, all environment variables can
>   be specified in the "setenv" script. The script is placed either into
>   CATALINA_BASE/bin or into CATALINA_HOME/bin directory and is named
>   setenv.bat (on Windows) or setenv.sh (on *nix).

So just add the following line to `setenv.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

This way you are setting the variable **locally**.

Answer (score 1):

I have that same problem but I solve it by changing 
JDK_DIR variable in `/etc/init.d/tomcat` as follow :

```
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install Java using the repository of http://www.webupd8.org .

This is for Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html